# Rails: facebook oauth: get user profile link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

I have a rails app where users can log through facebook with oauth.

I retrieve their image, email and name. What I'd like to do is scrap their profile link (http://facebook.com/name) and gender (male,female, other)

But It doesn't work for link and gender, here is my integration:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

**User.rb model**

```
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
        user.gender = auth.info.gender # assuming the user model has a gender
      user.link = auth.info.link # assuming the user modal has a link
      end
    end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
```

EDIT

**devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "***", "***"
```

But for all users, gender and link return 'nil'

Any ideas what I could be missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Try inspecting the value of `auth` hash returned by omniauth after authentication. See if the hash has the values returned. If not then that would be because of that particular user's privacy settings.

Comment: It's returning nil, but I tried with a profile completely open, and the hash is nil  as well. But I think that the link value is part of the public profile, meaning it can't be hidden by the user... no matter how private his profile is.

Comment: Did you check the auth hash returned? the structure of it, and how there are other fields present, etc.

Comment: The omniauth-facebook docs has described an example hash which shows that the gendeer, link info isn't in the `info` key, it's nested within `extra``raw-info` key : https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash

Answer (score 1):

The `url` parameter doesn't work now, the correct name of the field is `link`

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', {scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name,verified,gender,link'}
```

There is a list of attributes we can get from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-public_profile

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the scope and fields you want to get when you specify the provider in config/initializers/devise.rb

I.e.:

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', {scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name,verified,gender,url'}
```

Whether or not facebook will give you all the data you ask for is a different question.

Comment: I am confused, I edited my answer with devise.rb file, and I did not provide any score and fields inside. I still get the email and name ...

Comment: It's "scope" not "score".  Facebook may default to giving you some of the fields even if you don't specify them (though it's good to specify them if that changes tomorrow).  Some fields you won't get unless you do specify them.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. Thank you David!